# Can I use SE after deactivating Facebook account?

Tags: discussion, login, sign-up

1. Can I use StackExchange services if I deactivate my facebook account
   which I used for signing up to StackExchange?
2. Can I change my SE nickname, or am I stuck to my Facebook login name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add *other* login credentials to your account; using Google, Yahoo, the Stack Exchange OpenId provider, or any other OpenID account service. Do this *before* you lose access to your Facebook account!

Your nickname is not tied to any of those accounts, you can change it (with some rate limiting) to something else.

Comment: But to be explicitly clear, if you deactivate the only credential you have on record with us (e.g. Facebook), you won't be able to access your account once you log out/get logged out/use a different device, etc.